# Filling in missing data in rows without using a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table in this form (simplified down) :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Extension] [varchar](30) NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [StartTimestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserId] [varchar](30) NULL DEFAULT (''),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Consider this data:

```
Id | Extension | StartTimestamp      | UserId
------------------------------------------------
1  |  100      | 2018-09-24 16:00:00 | A 
2  |  101      | 2018-09-24 16:01:15 | B
3  |  100      | 2018-09-24 16:01:14 | 
4  |  102      | 2018-09-24 16:02:24 | C
5  |  100      | 2018-09-24 16:05:00 | A
6  |  101      | 2018-09-24 16:07:00 | B 
7  |  101      | 2018-09-24 16:30:00 |
8  |  100      | 2018-09-24 17:00:00 | D
```

Now I want to fill in the gaps for the UserId column following this rule:
A record for a certain extension and not older than 10 minutes
So for row with Id 3 that would mean UserId A (as it would find record with Id 1). And for row 7 the UserId would stay empty as it fails to find a record within 10 minutes for this extension.
Currently I am using this query to identify extensions that have a gap (in conjunction with a cursor):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT b.Extension
FROM test b
 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Extension
   FROM test
   WHERE
    UserId = ''
   ) a ON a.Extension=b.Extension
 WHERE
  b.UserId <> ''
 ORDER BY b.Extension
```

Is it possible to achieve this without using a cursor (ie using a single update statement)?

Comment: is it the most recent record within the last 10 minutes?  There could be more than 1

Comment: yes there could be more than one. but that does not matter as the userid wont change for a given extension in a timeframe of 10 minutes. But the most recent record would more "correct"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when userid is not null then userid
             when (lag(StartTimestamp) over (partition by Extension 
 order by StartTimestamp) > 
                   dateadd(minute, -10, StartTimestamp)
                  )
             then lag(userid) over (partition by Extension 
 order by StartTimestamp)
        end) as imputed_userid
from test t;
```

Comment: @whosrdaddy . . . It was a small typo.  The parentheses was missing on `dateadd()`.  This seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: @whosrdaddy . . . That depends on what filtering is needed.  The safest method is a subquery/CTE with the lag and then filtering outside it.

Comment: I see, I need to filter the imputed_userid. Using a subquery works fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
with Changes as (SELECT t1.id FROM test t1 
                        CROSS APPLY 
                                    (SELECT TOP 1 t2.UserId from test  t2 where
                                                             t2.Extension = t1.extension 
                                                            and  t1.id != t2.id 
                                                            and t2.starttimestamp 
                                                              between dateadd(minute,-10,t1.starttimestamp) 
                                                              AND t2.starttimestamp 
                                                            ORDER BY t2.starttimestamp DESC) DQ
                        WHERE COALESCE(t1.userid,'') = '' 
                )
                Update Test SET UserId = 
                        (SELECT UserId from changes WHERE Changes.Id = test.Id 
                            AND EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROm Changes c2 WHERE c2.Id = test.Id)
                        )
```

Comment: 'Changes' should only include the id's that needs to be updated, and you only want to update what needs to change.  EXISTS. selects the rows in Test that were flagged in 'Changes'.  So if not selected in 'CHanges', then it will not EXIST as a match

Comment: Hi Cato, I have an issue in a sense where I have data spanning over multiple days and it finds the wrong UserId

Comment: so is your id only unique to the day?  My answer assumes id is a unique field.

Comment: No, Id is unique but I can have multiple users per extension. I tried out your query and it is linking the wrong user to the extension for a given period.

Comment: when you say it's the 'wrong user' - I noticed a bug where it could choose the row you are on, but also, not clear how to select which one of multiple users - or maybe it just doesn't work, no time to key all your test data in

Comment: Anyway, LAG() works and returns correct results. Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used ROW_NUMBER() to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Extension] [varchar](30) NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [StartTimestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserId] [varchar](30) NULL DEFAULT ('')
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Extension, StartTimestamp, UserId)
SELECT 100, {ts'2018-09-24 16:00:00.000'}, 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 101, {ts'2018-09-24 16:01:15.000'}, 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 100, {ts'2018-09-24 16:01:14.000'}, ''  UNION ALL
SELECT 102, {ts'2018-09-24 16:02:24.000'}, 'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 100, {ts'2018-09-24 16:05:00.000'}, 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 101, {ts'2018-09-24 16:07:00.000'}, 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 101, {ts'2018-09-24 16:30:00.000'}, ''

SELECT
    a.Id, a.Extension, a.StartTimestamp, a.UserId, b.StartTimestamp, b.UserId
FROM @temp a
JOIN (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Extension ORDER BY b.StartTimestamp) RowNo,
        a.Id, a.Extension, b.StartTimestamp, b.UserId
    FROM @temp a
    JOIN @temp b ON b.Extension = a.Extension -- edited to add this
    AND LEN(b.UserId) > 0
    AND b.StartTimestamp >= DATEADD(mi, -10, a.StartTimestamp)
    AND b.StartTimestamp < DATEADD(mi, 10, a.StartTimestamp)
    WHERE a.UserId = ''
) b ON b.Id = a.Id AND b.RowNo = 1
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your answer. While your answer works, its has 2 problems: it is very slow and it only finds one record (but maybe that's my fault because I didn't state that there could be multiple gaps for a same given extension)

Comment: Hi.. I have added to the join clause... I had miss matching on the extension.. should work hopefully now and speed up the process
"UPDATE a SET UserId = b.UserId" in place of the top SELECT to actually do the update